# mongoose update selected fields only or insert

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The title might sound like `findOne` with `$set` but somehow I am not getting it to work as the way I wanted though.

To start, I have a schema of Ticket

```
const Ticket = new Schema(Object.assign({
    ticketNumber: { type: String, required: true },
    year: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: [] },  // object

}, BaseSchema), { timestamps: true });
```

then I have a function to write data to db.

I have a mock up data within the code below too

```
exports.writeToDB = async () => {
    const data = [
        {
            ticketNumber: 123456789,
            year: 2019,
            notes: 'hello there',
            more: 'there should be more fields here'
        },
        {
            ticketNumber: 987654321,
            year: 2020,
            notes: 'hello there again',
            more: 'there should be more fields here again'
        }
    ];

    data.forEach(d => {
        console.log(d, 'ddd');
        const { ticketNumber, year, ...contents } = d;
        const query = { ticketNumber };
        const update = {
            'year': { [year]: contents }
        };
        const options = { upsert: true };
        Ticket.updateOne(query, update, options, (err, doc) => {
            console.log(doc, 'docc');
        })
    })
};
```

in the schema, there's only `ticketNumber` and `year`
Everything is fine to start with but what I am trying to do is, the year might differ and the `ticketNumber` would stay the same. Each time when data is passed in and if `ticketNumber` is found then `update` according to `year`, if `year` is not found then `insert` instead.

a sample of what'll be in db is

```
{
    ticketNumber: 123456789,
    year: {
        2019: {
            notes: 'hello there',
            more: 'there should be more fields here'
        }
    }
};
```

if data is passed in with the same year `2019` then it'll update the `notes` and `more` fields plus other fields but if data is passed in with a different year such as `2020` then what is in db should look like...

```
{
    ticketNumber: 123456789,
    year: [
        2019: {
            notes: 'hello there',
            more: 'there should be more fields here'
        },
        2020: {
            notes: 'hello there',
            more: 'there should be more fields here'
        },
    ]
};
```

I tried to configure my `update` variable into such

```
const update = {
    $set: {'year': { [year]: contents }}
};


const update = {
    'year': $set{ [year]: contents }
};
```

but both of them are not working though,  first one would overwrite the whole object (kind of what is expected).  Second one actually does nothing at all

Any suggestions on what I should be doing or there are other logic I should provide instead of using something like `$set`?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the mongoose api, and the `Model.update` method has this note in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update):

All top level keys which are not atomic operation names are treated as set operations:

**Example**:

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.update(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback);

// is sent as
Model.update(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, function(err, res));
// if overwrite option is false. If overwrite is true, sent without the $set wrapper.
```

So that means, you don't have to manually specify `$set` when using `Model.update` on mongoose, just do the following:

```
const update = {
    [`year.${year}`]: contents
};
```

Comment: ah, great! thanks a lot, didn't know we can write it this way.  PS  I have to make `year.${year}` a variable first else I would get an error just making an obj that way. so I had to do something like this         `const k = \`year.${year}\`;
        const update = {
            [k]: contents
        };`

Comment: @Dora ah yeah, I'll fix that.